# SQL Server : record handling advice needed

Tags: sql-server, token

I am having issues trying to successfully keep track of tokens that I send to my server. The tokens are used for GCM notifications in an Android App.

The scenario is this: when a user installs the app, I create a GCM token, store it in shared preferences and send it to my server for storage so I can send a notification at a later time. This part is easy. No problem storing the token on my server and the app users phone. I can send general notifications to end users who have not registered an account in the app.

If the user registered an account and log in their account, I update and associate the user id with the token. This helps me when I want to send specific notifications to a single app user. Still easy so far.

Here is my tables and stored procedure for updating

```
CREATE TABLE NOTIFICATION
(
    MESSAGEID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    TOKEN VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UID VARCHAR(128) NULL UNIQUE,
    USTAMP SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL, --know when token is updated
    ISTAMP SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL  --know when token was created
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGCMupdate]
    @T VARCHAR(255),
    @U VARCHAR (128),
    @RESULT TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @iU int
    --DECLARE @iT int
    --SET @iT = (SELECT COUNT(TOKEN) FROM NOTIFICATION WHERE TOKEN = @T)
    --SET @iU = (SELECT COUNT(UID) FROM NOTIFICATION WHERE UID = @U)

    UPDATE NOTIFICATION 
    SET UID = @U, USTAMP = DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()) 
    WHERE UID IS NULL 
      AND TOKEN = @T  --add uid to token

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE NOTIFICATION 
        SET TOKEN = @T, USTAMP =  DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()) 
        WHERE UID = @U -- handle a token update
    END

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @i int
        SET @i = (SELECT COUNT(TOKEN) FROM NOTIFICATION WHERE TOKEN)

        INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION(TOKEN, UID, USTAMP, ISTAMP) 
        VALUES (@T, @U, DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()), DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE())) --Insert new combo
    END  

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN    
        SET @RESULT = '1'
    END
    ELSE IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT = '0'
    END 

    SELECT @RESULT
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGCMinsert]
    @T VARCHAR(255),
    @U VARCHAR (128) = NULL,
    @RESULT TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION(TOKEN, UID, USTAMP, ISTAMP) 
    VALUES (@T, @U, DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()), DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()))

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN    
        SET @RESULT = '1'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @RESULT = '0'
    END

    SELECT @RESULT
END
GO
```

It is the `GCMupdate` stored procedure I am having trouble with. I install the app for the first time and I now have a token. Good stuff..  Then I register and log in, now I have a token with a user id.  Excellent...  Then I buy a new phone and download the app.  New token generated and stored, the problem is when I log in and try to update the newly created token I already have a userid stored in the table. I am not sure if have the UID unique is the best approach.

I am not sure if I should set my table up differently. I know I want to make sure I can keep track of the tokens with out errors. I think I may need some delete statements some where in the stored procedure, not sure.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically UID is not unique in the table because a given UID can have multiple tokens. Is there other processing which requires it to be unique? Are you intending a allow given USERID to actively use your app across many devices (tokens?). Is the problem that you only want to notify one active device at a time? I guess your error message is something about uniquness. The practical solution is remove he unique constraint, but what downstream effect dos this have? What other processes need this to be unique?

Comment: The app will only be used on smartphones with Bluetooth and primarily only used on site (at the car wash the app is designed for) .  There is no need for multiple devices to receive notifications.  It is a little complicated.  We could both have the app on our phones and each have separate accounts. Today I use your phone at the car wash because my battery is dead and I want to get my notifications after wash use. But tomorrow  I use my phone again, I want me to get my notifications on my phone and not your phone.  That is why I update the token with the with the user id upon log in. Thank you

Comment: If you don't care about storing history and remembering old devices and you just want to automatically move to the new device then then you should alter you proc to update the _token_ if the user id is already found. Does this appear to match your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more concise. It uses `RETURN` instead of `SELECT` to exit immediately, throws an error for an unexpected state. It also assumes that `USTAMP` and `ISTAMP` have a default defined. Not sure why you're adding 3 hours but you might want to look into timezone aware data types.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGCMupdate]
@T VARCHAR(255),
@U VARCHAR (128)
AS
BEGIN
    -- If this is a new user against existing token, update it
    UPDATE NOTIFICATION
    SET 
    USTAMP = DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()),
    USER = @U
    WHERE TOKEN = @T
    AND (USER IS NULL OR USER <> @U)

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
        RETURN 1 

    -- If this is an existing user against a different token 
    -- change the token
    UPDATE NOTIFICATION
    SET 
    USTAMP = DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()),
    TOKEN = @T
    WHERE USER = @U
    AND TOKEN <> @T

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       RETURN 2

    -- Completely new
    INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION(TOKEN, UID)
    SELECT @T, @U
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM NOTIFICATION
        WHERE TOKEN = @T
        AND USER = @U

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       RETURN 3


    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM NOTIFICATION
        WHERE TOKEN = @T
        AND USER = @U
        )
        RETURN 4 -- Already exists. No change

    THROW 60000 ,'Unexpected State encountered'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions Nick.  It helped me come up with a solution.  I don't know if this is the best solution but it seems to meet all the requirements and it is the best I can come up with this evening,  Maybe with some sleep I will come up with something better.  I am sure there is room for improvement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGCMupdate]
@T VARCHAR(255),
@U VARCHAR (128),
@RESULT TINYINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PAIR int
        SET @PAIR = (SELECT COUNT(TOKEN) FROM NOTIFICATION WHERE TOKEN = @T AND UID = @U)

    IF (@PAIR = 1) -- the Token and Userid are already paired no update required
           BEGIN
           SET @RESULT = '1' -- all good
           END
    ELSE IF (@PAIR = 0) -- attempt to pair
               BEGIN
           UPDATE NOTIFICATION SET UID = @U, USTAMP = DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()) WHERE UID IS NULL AND TOKEN = @T  --add uid to token
               END
        ELSE IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
               BEGIN
           UPDATE NOTIFICATION SET TOKEN = @T, USTAMP =  DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()) WHERE UID = @U -- handle a token update
               END  
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0 AND @PAIR =0)  -- Last Resort
           BEGIN
           DELETE FROM NOTIFICATION WHERE TOKEN = @T OR UID = @U -- delete Token and User Id 
           INSERT INTO NOTIFICATION(TOKEN, UID, USTAMP, ISTAMP) VALUES (@T, @U, DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE()), DATEADD(HH, 3, GETDATE())) --Insert new pair
               END
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
               BEGIN 
               SET @RESULT = '1'
               END
        ELSE IF (@@ROWCOUNT=0 AND @PAIR =0)  
               BEGIN 
               SET @RESULT = '0'
               END

    SELECT @RESULT
END
```

Comment: I hope that solved it for you. There are ways to simplify the code but it seems what we are missing here is a clear description of the business rules, i.e. when a user tries to pair with a different device what do you want to happen?

Comment: I would like to allow user to pair with a different device. The goal is to keep track of the very last device the user used.  :)